# Click on a button to change multiple span items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have multiple span items such as

```
<span>A</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>C</span>
<span>D</span>
```

and a div (which I will change to a button later) called "change".

```
<div id="change">CHANGE</div>
```

Is there a way to change the text of all the span items on the page with a single button click?

I'm not very familiar with JavaScript and so far, I'm trying this code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#change').click(function(){
        $("span").replaceAll(function(){
            while ('span') {
                if ($('#span').text() == 'A') {
                    return $('span').text('B');
                }
                else if ($('span').text() == 'B') {
                    $('span').text('C');
                }
                else if ($('span').text() == 'C') {
                    $('span').text('D');
                }
                else if ($('span').text() == 'D') {
                    $('span').text('A');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/d4ewwqm5/

Comment: Do you want to change each span text individually or change all of the texts to the same text ?

Answer (score 3):

**Simple example:** altering the content from the `text()` callback:

```js
$("#change").on("click",function() {
 $("span").text(function(i,txt) {
   return {
     "A":"B",
     "B":"C",
     "C":"D",
     "D":"A"
   }[txt];
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>A</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>C</span>
<span>D</span>
<button id="change">CHANGE</button>
```

IF your `span` elements are **grouped** you could use `.append()` to parent:

```js
$("#change").on("click", function(){
  $("#spans").append( $("#spans span").eq(0) )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spans">
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>C</span>
  <span>D</span>
</div>
<button id="change">CHANGE</button>
```

If your SPANS are **not grouped** (irrelevant position in DOM), but rather share a same className you could:

- `map` your `<span>`s content into array of contents
- modify the array
- finally send the modified array to each SPAN

```js
var spans = $(".spn");

// Map spans content into Array
var conts = spans.map(function(){
  return this.innerHTML;
}).get();


$("#change").on("click", function(){
  
  // Modify the Array first

  // DIRECTION >>>
  // conts.unshift(conts.pop());

  // DIRECTION <<<
  conts.push(conts.shift());

  // Than send the array values to spans
  spans.text(function(i){
    return conts[i];
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="spn">A</span>
<span class="spn">B</span>
<span class="spn">C</span>
<span class="spn">D</span>
<button id="change">CHANGE</button>
```

Yes, in all examples you can **click and perform the *switch* as many times you want**!
If you don't want that, than instead of `.on(` use `.one(`

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you just wants to change span text on click conditionally you can loop all `span` by using [JQuery each() Method](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=each):

HTML:

```
<span>A</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>C</span>
<span>D</span>
<br><br><br>
<div id="change">CHANGE</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#change').click(function(){
            $("span").each(function(){

                if ($(this).text() == 'A') {
                    return $(this).text('B');
                }
                else if ($(this).text() == 'B') {
                    $(this).text('C');
                }
                else if ($(this).text() == 'C') {
                    $(this).text('D');
                }
                else if ($(this).text() == 'D') {
                    $(this).text('A');
                }            
        });        
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xpadzam8/

Comment: There's no need to each! You could simply use a `.text(function(idx, textContent){})` callback since `$("span")` is already a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that easily, for example with jquery your click can be catch with :

```
$("#change").on("click",function(){
 $("span").text(function(i,txt){
    switch(txt){
       case "A" : $(this).text("B"); break;
       case "B" : $(this).text("C"); break;
       case "C" : $(this).text("D"); break;
       case "D" : $(this).text("A"); break;
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Why `each` when you could do `$("span").text(function(i,txt){`

Comment: It's even cleaner without the `switch` ([see my answer edit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36790422/383904))

Answer (score 0):

try this hack

```
 $('#change').click(function(){
        var f = $("span").first();
        var c = f.detach();
        var l = $("span").last();
        c.insertAfter(l)

    });
```

```js
$('#change').click(function() {
  var f = $("span").first();
  var c = f.detach();
  var l = $("span").last();
  c.insertAfter(l)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spans">
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>C</span>
  <span>D</span>
</div>
<button id="change">CHANGE</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/), you will see that your usage of replaceAll() is incorrect.

Use [repalceWith](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

Also, since you want to replace all the spans with one click, get rid of the if-else.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i made some changes in your code, you can have a look on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hearty/x1c2tgzp/1/)

```
$('#changeText').click(function(){
    $("span").text("my text");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code what you need is `.each()` and `$(this).html();` function.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
$('#change').click(function(){
 $('span').each(function(){
   if ($(this).html() == 'A') {
     $(this).html('B');
   }
   else if ($(this).html() == 'B') {
     $(this).html('C');
   }
   else if ($(this).html() == 'C') {
     $(this).html('D');
   }
   else if ($(this).html() == 'D') {
     $(this).html('A');
   }
 });
});
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/d4ewwqm5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.If you want to change the text of all spans with the same text you can just select all spans.Like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#change').click(function(){
    $("span").text('your text');
    });
 });
```

If you want to change each span individually with a custom text (in your code you seem to replace the text of each span with the text of the next span, except for the last one which takes the text of the first one) you should iterate through spans with `.each()` .That would work no matter where the spans are located in page.In case you want to select only spans with a certain class just replace `span` with `span.yourclass`.Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#change').click(function(){

    var first=$("span").first().text(); //store the text of the first span

    $("span").not(':last').each(function(){ //select all spans except last
    $(this).text($(this).next('span').text()); //change text of each span to text of next span
    });

    $("span").last().text(first);   //set the text of the last span to the text of the first 
    });
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fdkxu2dc/1/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#change').click(function(){
            $('span').each(function(){
                var txt=$(this).text();
                switch (txt){
                    case 'A': $(this).text('B');break;
                    case 'B': $(this).text('C');break;
                    case 'C': $(this).text('D');break;
                    case 'D': $(this).text('A');break;

                }
            })
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#changeButton').click(function (event) {
    var _changeMap = {
        A: 'B',
        B: 'C',
        C: 'D',
        D: 'E',
    };

    $('span').each(function (index, element) {
        element.innterText = _changeMap[element.innerText.trim()];
    });

    $.preventDefault();
});
```